# Monitor updates on a MongoDB collection (Post update hook on db layer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

One of my collection is getting updated by different micro-services. And the updates are being done by either **[monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk)** or **[mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)** libs.

So I wanted to monitor updates done on this collection. Also I do not have access to those services so I cannot add post update hooks on each services but I have access to db where I can do whatever I want. I am open to use any ORMs or libs.

> So basically - if any update query is triggered from any of the
>   services, my monitoring (hook or something) code should be triggered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongodb Change Streams to listen for data changes check out a sample app https://gist.github.com/riodw/74a839ab6964bceda8ff799d3ad33442

Mongodb docs https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/#change-streams

You can try the change stream from mongoose :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#change-streams

An example i just tried and it works :

```
let Congress = require("../models/congress");
// change stream
Congress.watch().
on('change', data => console.log('change stream',data));
//
```

Comment: Hey @petranb2, this doesnt work. The updates are being done from a different connection and I have added the changeStream watcher on a different server, could that be a reason?

Comment: @Rahul i just update my answer with change stream from mongoose. I tried at my own mongodb server and it works .